# Repopulate a form field from a different class in C#

Tags: c#, class, reference

I'm trying to repopulate a textbox from a separate class. I've looked through a number of instances of this same question and found what I thought was a good solution. But, I can't make it work.  I've tried to resolve the issue by creating a separate thread to send the data back. I don't know if this is a great idea or not. But, I know the data is getting back to the correct place without it because it shows up in the console.  Any suggestions?  Thanks!

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void updater(double value)
    {
        textBox1.Text = value.ToString(); // Trying to update here
        Console.WriteLine(value);  // The new multiple makes if back to here...
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CALC c = new CALC();
        c.valuecalculator(.0025);
    }
}

public class CALC
{
    public void valuecalculator(double multiplier)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < 1000; index++)
        {
            Form1 f = new Form1();
            double newMultiple = index * multiplier;
            f.updater(newMultiple);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you think about what's happening here - you are creating a new instance of the form every time your value calculator calculates something. Your new instance isn't the same form that you are currently clicking the button on (it's one that's just sitting in memory and never gets shown on the screen) - a better approach would be to make the `valuecalculator` function return a value and populate the form with the value within the `button1_Click` event. I'd recommend learning about instances/reference types and what's happening with the `new` keyword - this might help you get your head around it

Answer (score 2):

You're making a new copy of the form in your valuecalculator method, but you should be using the same form.

There are loads of ways to solve this.

You could pass an instance of the form into your valuecalculator method.

You could make the reference to the form static in your `Program.cs` or whatever startup file originally initialises it.

You could give the form a reference to itself

You could put the code to update the form in the button1 click event (this makes most sense) by making the valuecalculator return the result instead of returning void

Answer (score 0):

Your components should only do one thing. The calculator should perform a calculation and return the result:

```
public static class Calc
{
    public static double CalculateValue(double multiplier)
    {
        return 100 * multiplier;
    }
}
```

Forms should be as simple as possible. Meaning they are only concerned with displaying form elements and passing events to event handlers. The actual logic that happens in these event handlers should be someone else's responsibility. I like to pass this logic in the constructor:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1(Func<double, double>CalculateValue)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        button1.Click += (sender, eventArgs) => textBox1.Text = CalculateValue(.0025).ToString();
    }

}
```

Constructing and connecting classes with each other is another responsibility. The simplest version is to use your Main() method:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        var form = new Form1(Calc.CalculateValue);
        Application.Run(form);
    }
}
```

Comment: His question is a very beginner one, I am not sure `Func` parameters are a good way to understand the basics of programming... and you'd pass an instance of Calc rather than a single method in, I hope, and stop it being static if you want to make it a bit nicer.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I just discovered that background workers do this seamlessly using the ProgressChanged event.